# I am getting the following error while trying to use the library function fminunc in octave

Tags: octave

error: 'cholupdate' undefined near line 209 column 14

error: called from

fminunc at line 209 column 12
ex2 at line 86 column 13

Comment: We can't read your brain, nor your code for that matter. Please upload the code you used to get this error in a [mcve].

Comment: When i type cholupdate in the command window it says undefined. However it should have been present see: http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/cholupdate.html

Comment: What is your octave version ?

Comment: version is 4.0.1. I think I need to add something to the loadpath, trying to figure out which directory.

Comment: try starting "octave -f". If "cholupdate" works then you should show your startup files and mention which operating system and show some code

Comment: it still doesn't work after octave -f. I tried to find the file for cholupdate definition but there is no such file. I could find the file for other functions. I am thinking of reinstalling and using the version 4.0.0

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't use GNU Octave at all if you aren't able to tell which operating system you are using

Comment: cholupdate is in the file Octave\lib\octave\4.0.1\oct\i686-w64-mingw32\chol.oct NOTE: the filename is chol.oct Please add the download link where you've downloaded GNU Octave (yes, there are different builds)

Answer (score 0):

My C drive had run out of space so the installation probably didn't succeed properly.
Reinstalling Octave after clearing space has fixed the issue.
Thanks for your help.